# App not compatible with tablet

Tags: google-play, tablet, android

I've build an Android app...for phones...but I wouldn't mind to broaden my audience and let Tablet owners download it as well....
To be honest. it doesn't look very neat on a tablet...but I don't really mind that. I'll at least give them the option.

unfortunately I cant find the app on the Google Play Store / Android Market with my tablet! when I launch the url directly in the browser, I am being redirected to the Play store, but it says "this app is not compatible with your device"

I didn't specify anything in my Manifest like "android:xlargeScreens" (the default should be true, right?
I also didn't specify any device restrictions in the Store Publish page

Unfortunately I only have one tablet to test it with...so I don't know if it's the tablets fault, my apps fault or the Play Store's fault....

I have an HP Touchpad (CM9)....it's rather experimental device - but other phone apps works without a problem on that device

while developing, I also used my tablet as a test device, and the app launched on it. so I don't really know why the Play Store is forbidding me to download the app....

are there any special requirement that my Manifest or my XML-layouts have to match, for the Play Store to open it for tablet users as well?

Comment: Did you specify a <uses-sdk>. android:minSdkVersion or android: targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Yes, min sdk is set to 7, target sdk is set to 15 - my tablet has Android 4.0.3 (15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my own problem:

I did 2 things:

1 - I disabled 'touchscreen'

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />
```

this disables ADVANCE touchscreen controls (like flicking etc.)

but I think the thing that did it was the following:

2 - I disabled the Copy Protection in the Play Store Publish page
a few hours later I could find my app on my tablet and install it!

Comment: Apologies for the vote down, but (in my opinion) the answer above is more useful - particularly the part about reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html - it explains and answers all the compatibility issues that I came across, similar to yours.

Comment: @PaulHiggins I have the following permissions in the manifest. Will my app show up for tablets? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3

Comment: hey, How to disable copy protection in Play Store Publish Page?

Answer (score 16):

The tablet may not support some of the features that your app requires. You can make them "not required" for the app (that means that you should check if they are actually available before using them in the code).

It is done like that:

```
<!-- features -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"  android:required="false" />
```

Other possible features are:

> android.hardware.camera
>
> android.hardware.camera.autofocus
>
> android.hardware.location.gps
>
> android.hardware.location
>
> android.hardware.location.network

For full list of relations between features<->permissions, you can see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

See "Feature reference"

Comment: I disabled all those features you've just listed.... I still get the 'app is not compatible' message on the tablet :-\

Comment: on the market, there is a way to see all the features that you require. See if there is anything else, and if there is - make it not required as well (there are many other features, like bluetooth, microphone, etc.). If this is not the problem, then maybe you are not supporting the android OS version of the device?

Comment: My app doesn't require anything specific - its just a simple mini-app with less than 5 classes in total. The market just says it requires FULL INTERNET ACCESS and VIEW NETWORK STATE.
and also: REQUIRES ANDROID: 2.1 and up.
my Tablet has Android 4.0.3
I already tested it out on tablet of a friend of mine. and it wasnt compatible with his either!

BUT both tablets arent listed in the Play Store Device Database on the Publish-page. could that be it?

Comment: I have the following permissions in the manifest. Will my app show up for tablets? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3

Answer (score 5):

write below code into your android manifest.xml file for make application tablet compatible.

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I tried it - still get the message that the app isn't compatible

Comment: above tag is already written in manifest than also doesn't appear on table?

Answer (score 1):

Android documentation clearly mentioned that if your app supporting v3.1+ then you should have  tag in AndroidManifest.xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html