# Apk file not installed in Tablets from android market?

Tags: android, apk

I developed an application and uploaded the apk file to  android market. It is installed and working properly in all handset devices but it is **not installing in tablets**. But, if i am installing the apk directly into the tablet its working.

i used the following in my manifest file.

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" />
              />
```

Comment: is `<supports-screens>` in the right place?

Comment: i am using galaxy nexus 7 tablet and placed <supports-screens> in the correct place

Comment: Could you please show your whole Manifest? This might have something to do with other elements like <use-feature> for instance.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.karmakexpo" android:versionCode="4"  android:versionName="1.3" ><uses-permission  
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5"/>
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"android:smallScreens="true"android:normalScreens="true"android:largeScreens="true"android:anyDensity="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Comment: @user1525067 Please see my answer and if my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your application fails to stretch for tablet screen size.

Please pay attention to following:

**An application "supports" a given screen size if it resizes properly to fill the entire screen.** Normal resizing applied by the system works well for most applications and you don't have to do any extra work to make your application work on screens larger than a handset device. However, it's often important that you optimize your application's UI for different screen sizes by providing alternative layout resources. For instance, you might want to modify the layout of an activity when it is on a tablet compared to when running on a handset device.

However, **if your application does not work well when resized to fit different screen sizes, you can use the attributes of the  element to control whether your application should be distributed to smaller screens or have its UI scaled up ("zoomed") to fit larger screens using the system's screen compatibility mode.** When you have not designed for larger screen sizes and the normal resizing does not achieve the appropriate results, screen compatibility mode will scale your UI by emulating a normal size screen and medium density, then zooming in so that it fills the entire screen.

**Remove**

```
<supports-screens>
```

**and try using:**

```
<compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code line into your android manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />
```

And see below  link for more information.

[App not compatible with tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832664/app-not-compatible-with-tablet)