# My app still is not showing on the tablets with no SIM card store why?

Tags: android, permissions

My app features are:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true" ></supports-screens>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And I've added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
         android:required="false"
         />
```

on a phone it shows:

[image]

But still it does not appear on the tablets with no SIM card so what's the problem and is there a way to see if it will appear or not before uploading the apk on the store because I can't just upload several apks to test that...
thanks.

Comment: `But still "it" does not appear on the tablets` By "it" what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean the app; the app does not appear on the tablets this image is from a phone not from a tablet

Comment: Have you added the support screens tag in you manifest to support all types of devices ??

Comment: yes I did plz check the update

Answer (score 1):

Please add this feature in your `Manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" /> <br/>
```

*Reasons for adding this*:
The above provided is only a single feature that is not supported by any random Tablet. However, many tablets may not support various features that are provided by the regular handsets:

Here is the full list of the features:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Source: [App not compatible with tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832664/app-not-compatible-with-tablet) 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi but the tablet where I am checking the play store is a touchscreen tablet.. so I think that's not the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have not added the support Screen tag or compatible-screen tag in your manifest (must not use both together) i would suggest you to add support screen tag in your androidManifest.xml. this is how you can do it.

```
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: thank you but I've already added this in my manifest you can check it in the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've written the command: aapt dump badging project.apk
in the command line; but first you should access to the location of the aapt in your command line, then you should add your apk in the location of the aapt, then you write the command in the command line..
and I've viewed the features that are needed by the app and it seems that the android.hardware.location.gps was set to required and since gps is not supported by the tablet that I was searching for the app on, the app didn't show so I sat it to required=false and the app showed on the play store...