# Device compatibility Issue on Google Play

Tags: android, compatibility

Google Play (WEB) tells me that my app (Kompass PRO YACA) is incompatible with my devices. On my Devices PlayStore the app is compatible.
I can not find out where the Problem on Google Play is. So i uploaded a LITE version, a clone of PRO without some Features - same manifest. The LITE Version is compatible on both Google Play (WEB) and Device Playstore.

Is there a way to find out the reason for incompatibility of the PRO Version on Google Play? Please Help!

Comment: When logged-in in your Play Developers console, you can see the list of excluded device in the APK section of your app. When you open the windows by clicking on "Manage excluded devices" (even if number shows 0), you will se a combo box, where you can select "Unsupported". You can check if your device is listed there? I also see that your app is not compatible with a lot of my devices - perhaps due to implicitly required feature? For instance, telephony; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10833171/22099

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Issue.

I received this incompatibilty error on Google Play because I logged in with my developer account. But I can't buy my own app ;-))

Logging in with a different Account solved this issue.

Thanks for your help